# Javascript events firing in undesired order

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

## The problem:

`mouseout` event fires too early and causes the infobox to stay open when the user drags their mouse over the marker too fast. In other words... If the user quickly moves in and out of the marker... the `mouseover` event fires, then the `mouseout` event fires ... but then, the placesService callback is executed and `ib.open()` is called.

## The code:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

var request = {
    key: 'for_my_eyes_only',
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(some_lat, some_lng);,
    radius: '500',
    types: ["restaurant"]
};

var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.search(request, placesCallback);

function placesCallback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            var place = results[i];
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location,
            });

            //Infobox settings
                var ib = new InfoBox({
                    //a bunch of irrelevant properties.
                });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', markerMouseOverFactory(place, marker, ib));
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', markerMouseOutFactory(ib));
        }
    }
}

function markerMouseOverFactory(place, marker, ib){
    return function(){
        var detailService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        detailService.getDetails({reference: place.reference}, function(details, status){
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                ib.setContent(/*set some content using details*/);
                ib.open(map, marker);
            }
        });
    }

}

function markerMouseOutFactory(ib){
    return function(){
        ib.close();
    }
}
```

## The question:

Is there a way to abandon a google maps AJAX request? If I could abandon the AJAX request in the `mouseout` listener, all would be good. Or, how would you solve this? I tried using a simple flag in the mouseout, but couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method to cancel the request in the API as far as I know. But what I would do is to delay the callback executed inside the `mouseover` event. So that if the user holds the mouse longer than a specified time; it would mean he/she wants the `infobox` displayed.

#### Workaround:

```
var delayTimer, delay = 800; //less than 1 sec. delay
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    delayTimer = setTimeout(function() { 
        markerMouseOverFactory(place, marker, ib); 
    }, delay);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', markerMouseOutFactory(ib));
function markerMouseOutFactory(ib){
    clearTimeout(delayTimer); //clear timeout here
    return function(){
        ib.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this will do it for me. Thank you and +1 -- I will mark it as correct if no other less-hackish solutions come in ;) You've solved my issue for now.

Comment: No problem. I don't think this is too 'hackish' BTW. I would delay it even if there had been a way to cancel the request. If the user moves the mouse out that quick, it'll still mean, the request is not necessary.